# Makefile: "No such file or directory" for target file

Tags: gcc, makefile

First, I should admit makefiles are something that I'm very inexperienced at, so I apologize if this is an error that I should have been able to solve myself, but I have spent several hours on this, including reading the various answers on this site, and have been unable to discover a solution.

With that said, I have created the following makefile to compile my code on a Linux machine; it completes the sub compilations just fine, but when it comes to making the output itself, xPlatST, it throws an error.

```
g++ -std=c+=11 -g -Wall -pthread -c -o xPlatST.o xPlatST.cpp
g++ -std=c+=11 -g -Wall -pthread -c -o stdafx.o stdafx.cpp
g++ -std=c+=11 -g -Wall -pthread -c xPlatST xPlatST.o stdafx.o -L../hwloc
g++ error: xPlatST: No such file or directory
make: *** [xPlatST] Error 1
```

I believe it seems to think that the xPlatST is one of it's compilation files and thus can't find it, but for the life of me I can't work out why.

hwloc is a third party library, and should be unrelated to this issue. The code compiles just fine when compiled from the command line directly.

My files are xPlatST.cpp, xPlatST.h, stdafx.cpp, stdafh.h

Code is as follows:

```
CXX = g++ -std=c++11
INCLUDES =
LIBS = -L../hwloc 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -g -pthread
OBJS = xPlatST.o stdafx.o

xPlatST: ${OBJS}
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -c $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}

clean:
    -rm xPlatST *.o
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Your recipe is trying to use `xPlatST` as a source. Change the `-c` into a `-o` in your rule:

```
${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} ${INCLUDES} -o $@ ${OBJS} ${LIBS}
```

The `-c` flag tells the compiler to take all files, compile, and assemble them into an object file (`.o`). The `-o` flag specifies the destination file.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you; that explains a lot.

I had tried that, though not really understanding why before, but it just produced more errors so I assumed I must have been on the wrong track - turns out my include line was slightly wrong as well, and now it is all working fine.